# Attempted to divide by zero error on page load

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

Every time I load up a certain page, it gives out an error saying that I have attempted to divide by zero. After checking it, we found out that this only happens on our production link because we have published it on our local PC and it works just fine. Below is the query that we are using on the page:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM 
(
SELECT c.containerid
        ,wldw.wafernumber "Wafer"
        ,wldd.wipdatavalue "Item Qty"
        ,iqty.wipdatavalue "Integrator Qty"
        ,nd.wipdatavalue "Net Die"
        ,tr.wipdatavalue "Total Rejects"
        ,vi.wipdatavalue "Visual Inspection"
        ,tpedispo.wipdatavalue "TPE Disposition"
        ,pa.wipdatavalue "Pre Align"
        ,pa.wipdatavalue "Post Visual"
        , DECODE(NVL(iqty.wipdatavalue,0),0,0, ROUND((NVL(nd.wipdatavalue,0) / NVL(iqty.wipdatavalue,0))  * 100,2)) "Yield"
        ,comments.wipdatavalue "Comments"
        ,oper.wipdatavalue "Operator"
        ,pcwi.wipdatavalue "Inspector"
        ,engr.wipdatavalue "Engineer"
        ,wldw.waferstatus "Status"
        ,wl.wiplotid wiplothistoryid
        ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        ,wl.specid
        ,wldw.wafersequence
        ,1 as withdrilldown
        , gq.wipdatavalue WS_GROSSQTY
        , gd.wipdatavalue WS_GOODDIE
        , tq.wipdatavalue WS_TESTEDQTY
        , wr.wipdatavalue WS_TOTALREJECTS
        , vi.wipdatavalue WS_VISUALINSPECTION
        , td.wipdatavalue WS_TPEDISPOSITION
        , wc.wipdatavalue WS_COMMENTS
        , oqa.wipdatavalue OQAREJECTTYPE
        , wldd.wipdatanamename
  FROM Container C
  JOIN a_wiplot wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetails wld ON wl.wiplotid = wld.wiplotid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailswafers wldw ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = wldw.wiplotdetailsid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = wldd.wiplotdetailsid AND wldd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata nd ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = nd.wiplotdetailsid AND nd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND nd.wipdatanamename = 'WS_NET DIE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata iqty ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = iqty.wiplotdetailsid AND iqty.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND iqty.wipdatanamename = 'WS_INTEGRATOR QTY'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata tr ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = tr.wiplotdetailsid AND tr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TOTAL REJECTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata vi ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = vi.wiplotdetailsid AND vi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND vi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_VISUAL INSPECTION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata tpedispo ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = tpedispo.wiplotdetailsid AND tpedispo.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tpedispo.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TPE DISPOSITION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata pa ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = pa.wiplotdetailsid AND pa.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pa.wipdatanamename = 'WS_PRE ALIGN'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata pv ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = pv.wiplotdetailsid AND pv.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pv.wipdatanamename = 'WS_POST VISUAL'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata comments ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = comments.wiplotdetailsid AND comments.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND comments.wipdatanamename = 'WS_COMMENTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata oper ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = oper.wiplotdetailsid AND oper.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND oper.wipdatanamename = 'WS_OPERATOR'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata engr ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = engr.wiplotdetailsid AND engr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND engr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_ENGINEER'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata pcwi ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = pcwi.wiplotdetailsid AND pcwi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pcwi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_INSPECTOR'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata gq ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = gq.wiplotdetailsid AND gq.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND gq.wipdatanamename = 'WS_GROSS QTY'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata gd ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = gd.wiplotdetailsid AND gd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND gd.wipdatanamename = 'WS_GOOD DIE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata tq ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = tq.wiplotdetailsid AND tq.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tq.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TESTED QTY/SAMPLE SIZE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata wr ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = wr.wiplotdetailsid AND wr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND wr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TOTAL REJECTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata vi ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = vi.wiplotdetailsid AND vi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND vi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_VISUAL INSPECTION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata td ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = td.wiplotdetailsid AND td.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND td.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TPE DISPOSITION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata wc ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = wc.wiplotdetailsid AND wc.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND wc.wipdatanamename = 'WS_COMMENTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata oqa ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = oqa.wiplotdetailsid AND oqa.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND oqa.wipdatanamename = 'FOR OQA_REJECT TYPE'
 WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid = :ID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 1 AND wldd.wipdatanamename IN ('WS_ITEM QTY', 'WS_GROSS QTY')

UNION ALL
SELECT c.containerid
        ,wldw.wafernumber "Wafer"
        ,wldd.wipdatavalue "Item Qty"
        ,iqty.wipdatavalue "Integrator Qty"
        ,nd.wipdatavalue "Net Die"
        ,tr.wipdatavalue "Total Rejects"
        ,vi.wipdatavalue "Visual Inspection"
        ,tpedispo.wipdatavalue "TPE Disposition"
        ,pa.wipdatavalue "Pre Align"
        ,pa.wipdatavalue "Post Visual"
        , DECODE(NVL(iqty.wipdatavalue,0),0,0, ROUND((NVL(nd.wipdatavalue,0) / NVL(iqty.wipdatavalue,0))  * 100,2)) "Yield"
        ,comments.wipdatavalue "Comments"
        ,oper.wipdatavalue "Operator"
        ,pcwi.wipdatavalue "Inspector"
        ,engr.wipdatavalue "Engineer"
        ,wldw.waferstatus "Status"
        ,wl.wiplothistoryid
        ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        ,wl.specid
        ,wldw.wafersequence
        ,1 as withdrilldown
        , gq.wipdatavalue WS_GROSSQTY
        , gd.wipdatavalue WS_GOODDIE
        , tq.wipdatavalue WS_TESTEDQTY
        , wr.wipdatavalue WS_TOTALREJECTS
        , vi.wipdatavalue WS_VISUALINSPECTION
        , td.wipdatavalue WS_TPEDISPOSITION
        , wc.wipdatavalue WS_COMMENTS
        , oqa.wipdatavalue OQAREJECTTYPE
        , wldd.wipdatanamename
  FROM Container C
  JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wl.wiplothistoryid = wld.wiplothistoryid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailswafershistory wldw ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldw.wiplotdetailshistoryid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldd.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND wldd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory nd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = nd.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND nd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND nd.wipdatanamename = 'WS_NET DIE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory iqty ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = iqty.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND iqty.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND iqty.wipdatanamename = 'WS_INTEGRATOR QTY'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory tr ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = tr.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND tr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TOTAL REJECTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory vi ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = vi.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND vi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND vi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_VISUAL INSPECTION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory tpedispo ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = tpedispo.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND tpedispo.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tpedispo.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TPE DISPOSITION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory pa ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = pa.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND pa.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pa.wipdatanamename = 'WS_PRE ALIGN'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory pv ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = pv.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND pv.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pv.wipdatanamename = 'WS_POST VISUAL'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory comments ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = comments.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND comments.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND comments.wipdatanamename = 'WS_COMMENTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory oper ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = oper.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND oper.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND oper.wipdatanamename = 'WS_OPERATOR'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory engr ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = engr.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND engr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND engr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_ENGINEER'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory pcwi ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = pcwi.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND pcwi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND pcwi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_INSPECTOR'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory gq ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = gq.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND gq.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND gq.wipdatanamename = 'WS_GROSS QTY'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory gd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = gd.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND gd.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND gd.wipdatanamename = 'WS_GOOD DIE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory tq ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = tq.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND tq.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND tq.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TESTED QTY/SAMPLE SIZE'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wr ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wr.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND wr.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND wr.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TOTAL REJECTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory vi ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = vi.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND vi.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND vi.wipdatanamename = 'WS_VISUAL INSPECTION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory td ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = td.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND td.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND td.wipdatanamename = 'WS_TPE DISPOSITION'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wc ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wc.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND wc.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND wc.wipdatanamename = 'WS_COMMENTS'
  LEFT JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory oqa ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = oqa.wiplotdetailshistoryid AND oqa.waferscribenumber = wldw.waferscribenumber AND oqa.wipdatanamename = 'FOR OQA_REJECT TYPE'
 WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid = :ID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 1 AND wldd.wipdatanamename IN ('WS_ITEM QTY', 'WS_GROSS QTY')
) wd
ORDER BY wd."Wafer", wd.wafersequence
```

And also, the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Ext.Net;

namespace CamstarReportPortal.WebForms.MAXIMDataCollection.WaferSortMaxCIM
{
    public partial class MaxCIMWSTesterSummary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        static String wipkey;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                txtLot.Text = Request.QueryString["lotID"].ToString();
                txtSpec.Text = Request.QueryString["specname"].ToString();
                txtWipKey.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();

                wipkey = Session["ID"].ToString();

                uwgDataCollection.DataSourceID = whdsDataCollection.ID;
                uwgDataCollection.DataBind();
                uwgDataCollection.ExpandAll();
                CustomizeColumns(txtSpec.Text.Substring(0, 4));
                ExpirePageCache();
            }

            if (ddlInsertion.Items.FindByValue("%") != null)
            {
                //DO NOTHING
            }
            else
            {
                ddlInsertion.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("All", "%"));
            }
        }

        public void CustomizeColumns(string opCode)
        {
            if (uwgDataCollection.Bands.Count > 1)
            {
                switch (opCode)
                {
                    case "8628":
                    case "8337":                    
                    case "8622":
                        {
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[3].Hidden = true;//Sample Size
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[4].Hidden = false;//Tester Summary
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[5].Hidden = false;//IGS Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[6].Hidden = false;//Total Rejects
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[7].Hidden = false;//Yield
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[8].Hidden = false;//Variance
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[9].Hidden = true;//QA Test Result
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[10].Hidden = false;//Probemark Inspection 
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[11].Hidden = false;//Remarks
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[12].Hidden = true;//Remarks2
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[13].Hidden = false;//Operator
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[14].Hidden = false;//Engineer
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[15].Hidden = false;//Bin Failure
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = false;//Mismatch Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[17].Hidden = true;//Yield Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = true;//Reject Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[19].Hidden = false;//WAFERSTATUS
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[20].Hidden = true;//Elect. Rejects @ 8628
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[21].Hidden = false;//Adjustment Qty

                            if (opCode == "8622")
                            {
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = true;//Mismatch Disposition
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = false;//Reject Disposition
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "7628":
                    case "7337":
                    case "7629":
                    case "8537":
                        {
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[3].Hidden = false;//Sample Size
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[4].Hidden = false;//Tester Summary
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[5].Hidden = false;//IGS Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[6].Hidden = false;//Total Rejects
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[7].Hidden = false;//Yield
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[8].Hidden = false;//Variance
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[9].Hidden = false;//QA Test Result
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[10].Hidden = true;//Probemark Inspection 
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[11].Hidden = false;//Remarks
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[12].Hidden = true;//Remarks2
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[13].Hidden = false;//Operator
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[14].Hidden = false;//Engineer
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[15].Hidden = false;//Bin Failure
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = true;//Mismatch Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[17].Hidden = false;//Yield Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = false;//Reject Disposition
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[19].Hidden = false;//WAFERSTATUS
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[20].Hidden = false;//Elect. Rejects @ 8628
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[21].Hidden = false;//Adjustment Qty
                            if (opCode == "8537")
                            {
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[15].Hidden = true;//Bin Failure
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = false;//Mismatch Disposition
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[10].Hidden = true;//Probemark Inspection 
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[9].Hidden = true;//QA Test Result
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = true;//Reject Disposition
                            }
                            if (opCode == "7628")
                            {
                                this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[17].Hidden = true;//Yield Disposition
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    case "6103":
                        {
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[1].Hidden = true;//Integrator Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[2].Hidden = true;//Net Die
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[3].Hidden = true;//Total Rejects
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[4].Hidden = true;//Visual Inspection
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[5].Hidden = true;//TPE Dispo
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[6].Hidden = true;//Pre Align
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[7].Hidden = true;//Post Visual
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[8].Hidden = true;//Yield
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[9].Hidden = true;//Comment
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[10].Hidden = true;//Operator
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[11].Hidden = true;//Inspector
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[12].Hidden = true;//Engineer    
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[13].Hidden = true;//Status
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[14].Hidden = false;//WS Gross Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[15].Hidden = false;//WS Good Die
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = false;//WS Tested Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[17].Hidden = false;//WS Total Rejects
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = false;//WS Visual Inspection
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[19].Hidden = false;//WS TPE Dispo
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[20].Hidden = false;//WS Comments
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[21].Hidden = false;//OQ Reject Type

                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[14].Hidden = true;//WS Gross Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[15].Hidden = true;//WS Good Die
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[16].Hidden = true;//WS Tested Qty
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[17].Hidden = true;//WS Total Rejects
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[18].Hidden = true;//WS Visual Inspection
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[19].Hidden = true;//WS TPE Dispo
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[20].Hidden = true;//WS Comments
                            this.uwgDataCollection.Bands[1].Columns[21].Hidden = true;//OQ Reject Type   

                            break;
                        }
                };

            }
        }

        private void ExpirePageCache()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
        }

        protected void ddlInsertion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = ddlInsertion.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

            if (ddlInsertion.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "All")
            {
                uwgDataCollection.DataSourceID = whdsDataCollection.ID;
                uwgDataCollection.DataBind();
                uwgDataCollection.ExpandAll();
                CustomizeColumns(txtSpec.Text.Substring(0, 4));
                ExpirePageCache();
            }
            else
            {
                uwgDataCollection.DataSourceID = whdsDataCollectionAPB.ID;
                uwgDataCollection.DataBind();
                uwgDataCollection.ExpandAll();
                CustomizeColumns(txtSpec.Text.Substring(0, 4));
                ExpirePageCache();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

We made sure that there division by zero error is properly handled in the query and we do not have any computations on the code behind. Thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work ? `ROUND((NVL(nd.wipdatavalue,0) / NVL(iqty.wipdatavalue,0))`

Comment: Hello Nilesh, there is a decode function prior to that sql line. it is really weird because it was working on a local machine and that the error is only on our production link.

Comment: It is weird that I overlook the post and just comment:). Really not sure what is going on in there cause the query looks fine.